# Can't declare anything inside FB.api method

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, api, callback

I'm playing with facebook's javascript sdk and can't get the user email address to get sent to the server. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fbLogin(){
        FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
             console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
             $("<form id='fb_credentials' action='/create_user_with_fb'  method='post'></form>").appendTo('body');
             $("<input id='user_uid' type='hidden' />").appendTo("#fb_credentials");
             $("<input id='user_access_token' type='hidden' />").appendTo("#fb_credentials");
             $("<input id='user_email' type='hidden' />").appendTo("#fb_credentials");

             $("input#user_uid").attr({
               name: 'user[uid]',
               value: response.authResponse['userID']
             });
             $("input#user_access_token").attr({
               name: 'user[access_token]',
               value: response.authResponse['accessToken']
             });

             FB.api('/me', function(response){
                $("input#user_email").attr({
                   name: 'user[email]',
                   value: response.email
                });
             });
            $('form#fb_credentials').submit();

           } else {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
           }
         }, {scope: 'email, publish_actions, offline_access'});
    }
</script>
```

take note: The `fbLogin` function is called on an `onClick` event.

What I'm trying to do here is to fetch the user id, access_token and email using the JS SDK.
I then use JQuery to create a form and send the information via the http post method.

I can get all the information except for the user's email address. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the submit() call to inside the callback function definition for the FB.api call, i.e. move it up one line so that it is before the closing brace/paranthesis.  The way it is placed now, it is getting called before the FB.api call has finished, and thus before an email address has been returned and assigned to your form field.  Remember that FB.api is an asynchronous call, it does not block execution until it is finished.